# Guice injecting multiple parameters into constructor

Tags: java, guice

I have a class Worker that has a constructor that takes in 3 arguments, which are each a class with their own dependencies.

```
private A a; private B b; private C c;

@Inject
public Worker(A a, B b, C c) {
    this.a = a; this.b = b; this.c = c; 
}


public void run() {...}
```

In my main, which is in the Worker class, I have:

```
public void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new WorkerModule());
    a = injector.getInstance(A.class);
    b = injector.getInstance(B.class);
    c = injector.getInstance(C.class);

    run();   

}
```

My question is, how should I configure my module to allow for a getInstance for Worker(i.e injector.getInstance(Worker.class)) so I wouldn't have to call 3 injector.getInstances for the different dependency classes? And, how should I assign the worker in the worker class? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, by default Guice has on-demand injection enabled, so if your `A`, `B` and `C` are non-abstract classes, your module may be empty. Guice will automatically resolve dependencies if you ask it for `Worker` class instance:

```
Worker worker = injector.getInstance(Worker.class);
```

Here Guice will automatically create `A`, `B` and `C` instances and provide it to `Worker` constructor.

Second, your `main` method is non-static. It won't work as an entry point for your program. You should make it static. Then it could look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new WorkerModule());

    Worker worker = injector.getInstance(Worker.class);
    worker.run();
}
```

Comment: @Mozbi, if the answer was helpful, you should accept it. That's how stackoverflow works :)